# Embedding existing HTML in R markdown

Tags: html, r, rstudio, stargazer

Simple question,
is there a function to embedded an existing HTML output, in this case a table output from the stargazer package in R into an R Markdown script?

Comment: If you'd like to render as HTML, you should be able to simply place the HTML in the document. If you'd like to generate the HTML output from R and display as HTML, change the knitr option `result` to `=asis`.

Comment: I have an HTML document that I generated with Stargazer. It's in a WD. I want my Markdown file to 'read' it and embedded it in the output.  I can embedded the HTML fine, but I don't want it clogging up my rmd.

Comment: You might be able to use the `iframe` environment in your Rmd. <iframe src='path/to/your/file/html' ></iframe>. If not, this answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file) may help.

Comment: @NickReid what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

Horrible cluge, but this is what I did to get an html table into a xargian slide (based on another stack overflow answer).  The  line showed up in the slide unless I stripped it out.

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results='asis'}
t <-readLines("your_html.html")
len <- length(t)-1
cat(t[2:len])
```
````